# Darboux's theorem of several variables

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:U\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$  a differentiable function where $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$  open connected.
>
> What can we say about the image of the derivative $f'(U)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$?
>
> $f'(U)$ is connected?

If $n=1$ , $\;f'(U)$ is an interval by [Darboux's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29), some reference?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable isn't $f'$ continuous?

Comment: @Gaffney Not necessarily!

Comment: I think results relating to your question have been studied extensively. Googling "Weil" and "gradient problem" (simultaneously) will lead to some recent work that seems to be quite a bit more than what you're asking for.

Comment: MO: [Generalization of Darboux's Theorem](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/152605/generalization-of-darbouxs-theorem)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 1 :**
It seems that the proof below is wrong, since $\epsilon$ should depend on $x$ and thus $S$ is not necessarily connected.

**EDIT 2 :**  As answered in MathOverflow (in the [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152605/generalization-of-darbouxs-theorem) posted by @Martin Sleziak), it turns out that the generalization of Darboux's theorem doesn't hold.

<s>For $\epsilon$ sufficiently small</s>, consider : $$S = \{\ (\frac{f(x+te_1)-f(x)}{t},...,\frac{f(x+te_n)-f(x)}{t}) : x\in U \;,\, t\in (0,\epsilon_x)\ \}$$
Since $g:(x,t)$  $\rightarrow$ $(\frac{f(x+te_1)-f(x)}{t},...,\frac{f(x+te_n)-f(x)}{t})$ is continuous, <s>S is connected</s>. Moreover it's clear that $f'(U) \subset \overline S$ (*).

Now for $x \in U$ and $t\in (0,\epsilon),$ consider $h_x(t)=(f(x+te_1),...,f(x+te_n)).$ By the [Mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), there exists $t_0 \in (0,t)$ such that : $$\frac{h_x(t)-h_x(0)}{t}=h_x'(t_0)$$ which is equivalent to saying : $$(\frac{f(x+te_1)-f(x)}{t},...,\frac{f(x+te_n)-f(x)}{t})=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x+t_0e_1),...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(x+t_0e_n))$$ Hence $S \subset f'(U)$ (**).

By (*) and (**) we have : $S \subset f'(U) \subset \overline S$, therefore $f'(U)$ is connected.

Comment: You say that *By the Mean value theorem, there exists $t_0 \in (0,t)$ such that : $$\frac{h_x(t)-h_x(0)}{t}=h_x'(t_0)$$ which is equivalent to saying : $$(\frac{f(x+te_1)-f(x)}{t},...,\frac{f(x+te_n)-f(x)}{t})=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x+t_0e_1),...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}(x+t_0e_n))$$* - That's not correct!

Comment: To clarify @Yiorgos' comment, the mean value theorem gives you a $t_i$ which makes the $i$th component equal, but there is no reason for the $t_i$'s to all have the same value.

Comment: Note that I applied the mean value theorem to $h_x$ and not to each of the components, in order to have the same $t_0$

Comment: @Post No Bills, you are right, $\epsilon$ here depends on $x$, I introduced it to make sure $f(x+te_i)$ is well defined, I should then recheck if $S$ is still connected...

Comment: I'm not sure If I should delete the answer or not (I'm not sure of the protocol used in this site), anyway I just added a comment at the top and kept the answer in the case where the idea may inspire s.o for similar problems...

Answer (score 1):

The MathOverflow thread, linked in comments and answer, points to the paper [*Solution to the gradient problem of C.E. Weil*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmi/1136999135) by  Buczolich, in which he constructed a differentiable function $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $\nabla f(0)=0$ and $|\nabla f|\ge 1$ at all other points. I'd like to add that a shorter proof was found in [*A note on Buczolich's solution of the Weil gradient problem: a construction based on an infinite game*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10474-006-0096-7) by Malý  and Zelený (unfortunately, their article is behind Springer's paywall). An interesting aspect of the latter paper is the **game-theoretical** formulation:

> Let $B$ be an open ball in $\mathbb R^2$. The *point-line game* is a sequence of rounds. The first and the second players play  points $a_k\in B$ and lines $p_k$, respectively, obeying the following rules. In the first round, the first player plays a point $a_1\in B$ and then the second player plays a line $p_1$ with $a_i\in p_1$. In the $k$th round, the first player plays a point $a_k\in B\cap p_{k-1}$ and then the second player plays a line $p_k$ passing through $a_k$. The first player wins if the sequence $(a_k)$ diverges, otherwise the second player wins.

Malý  and Zelený prove

> **Theorem 1.2**. The second player has a winning strategy.

and reprove Buczolich's result based on this theorem.

Comment: This is an incorrect quote of Buczolich's theorem: He only proved that $|\nabla f(p)|\ge 1$ for **almost all** points $p\in R^2$.